# Call controller function from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, angularjs-scope

I'm new to AngularJS.
I want to build an app which could display book information and user could click an icon to remove the book information. I use a customer directive which display each book information. There is an icon on list of book information and user could click the icon to remove book information.

I have a ng-click listener on the icon in directive but I don't know how to let it call the function define in controller.

Could you tell me how to do it? Is there any better way to implement it?

Thanks

HTML code:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="bookCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="book in books | filter :{'name' : bookName}" book-List="book"></div> 
</div>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('bookCtrl', function ($scope,$http){
    $scope.books=[];
    $http.get("products.json")
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.books = response.data;   
    });

    $scope.removeItem = function(x){
        $scope.index = x;
        $scope.books.splice(x,1);
    }
});

app.directive('bookList', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: { item : '=bookList'},
        templateUrl: "template.html",
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="jumbotron" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="bookCtrl">
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{item.price}}</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" ng-click="removeItem($Index)"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>{{item.description}}</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an explicit scope property to your directive, it results in the creation of an isolated scope. This means that the directive will not be able to access methods outside the controller.

You may be able to achieve what you need by providing the method as a scope attribute to the directive that will remove the data.

A better approach would be to make use ng-model and contain the logic which modifies the data within the directive itself. I am unable to provide code examples as I am on a mobile device, although you can look around for examples.

Additionally, you may want to consider moving your http call to a service, for the sake of separating concerns.